# Render Javascript Data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a simple content_tag to pass data to javascript :

```
<%= content_tag :span, :class => 'attack-alert', data: { content: @received_attacks } do %>
    Attack
<% end %>
```

Now, @received_attacks is the content that is passed to a javascript file and is directly passed as text to a rollover effect.

My question is : Since i want some kind of formatting over the @received_attacks Array, what is the best approach to do that ? Is it ok to just pass a template to a variable and pass that instead of @received_attacks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider @received_attacks.to_json, JSON may be parsed simply by javascript

Comment: I know, but the problem is that i have just the plugin where i can only pass html or text to be shown, i have no control over the actual js representation. So, for now i use render_to_string.